# preg_replacement() for php array

Tags: php

I am genarating a dynamic php array $line.

```
echo "<pre>",print_r($line,1),"</pre>";
```

The array is in this format.

`"AARON,  ELVIA J",WATER RATE TAKER,WATER MGMNT,$81000.00,$73862.00`

What i need?Array should be like this

```
echo "<pre>",print_r($line,1),"</pre>";

AARONELVIAJ,WATER RATE TAKER,WATER MGMNT,$81000.00,$73862.00
```

What i had done:

```
        $re1='(")'; # Any Single Character 1
        $re2='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';   # Word 1
        $re3='(,)'; # Any Single Character 2
        $re4='(\\s+)';  # White Space 1
        $re5='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';   # Word 2
        $re6='(\\s+)';  # White Space 2
        $re7='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
        $re8='(")';

        $reg1="/".$re1.$re2."/";
        $reg2="/".$re3.$re4."/";
        $reg3="/".$re5.$re6.$re7.$re8."/";
        $line = preg_replace("/".'($reg1)$reg2($reg3)'."/", "$1$2", $line);//this is also generating the same array "AARON,  ELVIA J",WATER RATE TAKER,WATER MGMNT,$81000.00,$73862.00
        echo "<pre>",print_r($line,1),"</pre>";

        $pattern="/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7.$re8."/";
        $replacement="/".$re2.$re5.$re7."/";

        $values = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $line);
        $values = explode(',',$line);
        echo "<br>";
        $values =preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $values);
        $values=implode(',',$values);
        echo "<pre>",print_r($values),"</pre>";
        echo "<pre>",print_r($values,1),"</pre>";
```

What i am getting is like this:

```
AARON,ELVIAJ,WATERRATETAKER,WATERMGMNT,8100000,73862001
```

Someone please help me to find the solution

Comment: You might be better off using array_walk or array_map to apply a formatting function to all the elements in the array before attempting to output it.

Comment: I have tried array_map but this is not providing the required result.It is also giving the result like AARON,ELVIAJ,WATERRATETAKER,WATERMGMNT,8100000,73862001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
    $line = '"AARON,  ELVIA J",WATER RATE TAKER,WATER MGMNT,$81000.00,$73862.00';
    $pieces = explode('"', $line);

    $result = '';
    foreach ($pieces as $value) {
    if(substr( $value, 0, 1 ) === "," || substr($value, -1) == ','){
        $result .= $value;
    }else{
        $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
        $result .= str_replace(' ', '', $value);
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: It is generating the same array multiple times

Comment: I dint understand that.Is $line an element of an array?

Answer (score 0):

The [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function will do this for you perfectly.

```
$result = str_getcsv($line);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AARON,  ELVIA J
    [1] => WATER RATE TAKER
    [2] => WATER MGMNT
    [3] => $81000.00
    [4] => $73862.00
)
```

If you really want to remove the spaces and comma from the name, then you can add:

```
$result[0] = preg_replace('/\s+|,/', '', $result[0]);
```